# SET LANGUAGE fails because of case-sensitive system collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a built installation that is trying to execute the command `SET LANGUAGE english` on my SQL Server 2008R2 instance.

Though, the  SQL Collation (which is Case sensitive) makes it not find the Existing language alias `English` giving the error:

```
SET LANGUAGE failed because 'english' is not an official language name or a language alias on this SQL Server.
```

I can`t change the installation at all :(

How can I:
1. Create another Alias for `english` => `us_english`.
2. Change the alias `English` to `english`
3. Change the server to be Case Insensitive for the execution of the install

!! Rebuilding the Instance for different Collation, and then rebuilding back is an option to avoid. !!

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is for the installation, what do you reckon the odds are that the rest of the package has been well tested to work against a case sensitive server? You'd be better off going back to developers of the package and getting them to resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't think you have many options: the system collation can only be changed by [re-building the master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254(v=sql.105).aspx), and you can't apply the `COLLATE` clause to a `SET` statement. Ultimately this is an application bug: it assumes that SQL Server is case-insensitive. You don't mention which application but if it's closed-source you'll have to go to the vendor; if it's open-source you could patch it yourself (which may not be trivial, of course).

Comment: The Application is an Installer for Oracle Software..
Primavera, for being specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it wasn't the Case-sensitive/insensitive that affected it...
my collation was set on HEBREW_CS_..

rebuilt the Database with LATIN1_CS_..  and everything went well from there.
Both English, and english was accepted as languages :)

found the solution in a support forum for "Adobe Connector" :)

Home noone else will waste so much time on this :)